# Can I use low fat greek yogurt to substitute mayo in sauce that is going to be heated up (broiled)?

Tags: substitutions

I'm planning on making like a crab dynamite crusted salmon. Usually, the dynamite sauce is made with kewpie mayo or regular mayo. I try to stay away from mayo, so I thought about subbing the mayo for low fat greek yogurt. But, is it okay to heat greek yogurt up? Because I plan on putting the crab mixture on top of the salmon and broiling it but I wasn't sure if heating greek yogurt would cause some issues? I don't normally cook with it.

Comment: if the sauce is suppose to be completely smooth you probably cant do this substitution

Comment: well it doesn't really matter if its smooth or not i guess. I'm just putting mixing it with crab meat

Answer (score 4):

The yogurt will most likely separate and become watery under the broiler. Perhaps Mascarpone would be a good alternative. I use it whisked with a little half & half and a pinch of salt. It holds together better than mayo or other substitutes and doesn't overwhelm the flavor.